# multiselectfilter not working after refresh multiselectBox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used `jquery.multiselect.js` and `jquery.multiselect.filter.js`.
I used like following.

```
$('#ddlmy').multiselect({ noneSelectedText: $(this).attr('noneselectedvalue') }).multiselectfilter();
```

Note : noneselectedvalue is my custom property

Now my dropdownlist changed on selection of other dropdown and i refresh multiselect like following.

```
var updatedOption = $("#ddlmy").find('option');
$('#ddlmy').multiselect("refresh", updatedOption);
```

Its working good but after changing value, filter not working in multiselect box.

Comment: Well, the second time you do not seem to apply the multiselectfilter.
Otherwise, go to jsfiddle.net, and try to create a sample where this doesn't work as expected, update your post with this sample and an explanation of what you'd expect.

Comment: I am searching lots of related to issue on stack overflow but not find single question related to that issue. So i post this question.